# Elasticsearch query performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch to index two types of objects -

**Data details**

Contract object ~ 60 properties (Object size - 120 bytes)
Risk Item Object ~ 125 properties (Object size - 250 bytes)

Contract is parent of risk item (_parent)

I'm storing 240 million such objects in single index (210 million risk items, 30 million contracts)

Index size is - 322 gb

**Cluster details**

11 m2.4x.large EC2 boxes [68 gb memory, 1.6 TB storage, 8 cores](1 box is a load balancer node with node.data = false)
50 shards
1 replica

**elasticsearch.yml**

```yaml
node.data: true
http.enabled: false
index.number_of_shards: 50
index.number_of_replicas: 1
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 10000
index.merge.policy.use_compound_files: false
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
index.refresh_interval: 30s
index.store.type: mmapfs
path.data: /data-xvdf,/data-xvdg
```

I'm starting the elasticsearch nodes with following command - */home/ec2-user/elasticsearch-0.90.2/bin/elasticsearch -f -Xms30g -Xmx30g*

My problem is that I'm running following query on risk item type and it is taking about 10-15 seconds to return data, for 20 records.

I'm running this with a load of 50 concurrent users and a bulk index load of about 5000 risk items happening in parallel.

**Query** (With Join parent child)

http://:9200/contractindex/riskitem/_search*

```json
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "contract",
            "query": {
                "range": {
                    "ContractDate": {
                        "gte": "2010-01-01"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "and": [{
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": ["RiskItemProperty1"],
                            "query": "abc"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": ["RiskItemProperty2"],
                            "query": "xyz"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Queries from One Table

**Query1** (This query takes around 8 seconds.)

```
 <!-- language: lang-json -->

    {
        "query": {
            "constant_score": {
                "filter": {
                    "and": [{
                        "term": {
                            "CommonCharacteristic_BuildingScheme": "BuildingScheme1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "Address_Admin2Name": "Admin2Name1"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }



**Query2** (This query takes around 6.5 seconds for Top 10 records ( but has sort on top of it)

 <!-- language: lang-json -->

    {
        "query": {
            "constant_score": {
                "filter": {
                    "and": [{
                        "term": {
                            "Insurer": "Insurer1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "Status": "Status1"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can somebody please help me with how I can improve this query performance ?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer as well. Have you tried other kinds of relation between your documents ? I'm referring to Nested objects. I might be wrong but I would says that parent-child relation is sort of a "query-join". Nested objects are in the same Lucene block so it might be faster for search queries.

Comment: I also have a question... Why `Xms30g -Xmx30g` and not more ?

Comment: objects are very big and nested objects would require lot of space.

Comment: Also it would need reindexing whole document as any child object changes, and our use case is most of the time child documents would change

Comment: Have you consider using a numeric filter for the date query?

Comment: I had issues with performance when using an AND query. Instead, use a `Bool` with a `Must` with an array of `Term`? Also, I noticed you are using a `query` instead of a `filter query` - if you know the exact values of terms, you should switch your query to use   `"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {} }}` - this improved our queries tremendously. One more point, do you really need to return ALL the fields? Maybe use `_source` to get fewer fields in the result. For large results, this helps a lot too.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried custom routing? Without custom routing, your query needs to look in all 50 shards for your request. With custom routing, your query knows which shards to search, making queries more performant. More [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/customizing-your-document-routing/).

You can assign custom routing to each bulk item by including a routing value with the _routing field, as described in the [bulk api docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/bulk/).

Comment: What other options do we have other than custom routing?

Comment: As jackdbernier mentioned in his comment, increasing your heap size would help performance. This [thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Slow-Query-Performance-td4024165.html) is  almost a year old now, but its information is probably still good. For instance, the Elasticsearch team suggests here to set heap_size to 60% of overall memory. So, in your case, try increasing your heap to 40g.

Comment: Our normal queries are also slower, I have edited my posts with it.

Answer (score 1):

We made changes by using bitsets.

We ran 50 concurrent users (Read Only) for an hour. All our queries are performing 4 to 5 times faster, except parent child query (query in question) it has gone down from 7 seconds to 3 seconds.

I have one more query with has_child in it. Anyone else has any other feedback we can further improve this one, or other queries.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "LineOfBusiness": "LOBValue1"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "has_child": {
                    "type": "riskitem",
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "Address_Admin1Name": "Admin1Name1"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please comment/help?

Comment: Basically replace your AND/OR filters with BOOL. To take advantage of bitsets. NO idea why, but just do it and see if it's faster.